# 2D isometric tilemap coordinates

Tags: unity, isometric

I am learning Unity and for now trying to rotate a tilemap using (x, y) --> (-y, x).
I have created a Grid and tilemap in it
[image: Scene view]
As you can see my tiles are in cells of izometric tilemap.
I am expected that each diamond is represent 'cell' and have integer coordinates (x, y) like (0, 1), see the picture below
[image: Expected result]
But I can see that it is not work so

[image: Actual coordinates]

The problem is that if I try to use standart tilemap function like `GetTile` it is return wrong coordinates of the tile bcs it is use `Vector3Int` datatype, but in reality it seems obvious that coordinates is float. This problem leads to mistakes in rotation matrix.

It seems that when I chooce a cell layout property of tilemap to "Isometric" it is not change coordinate system to isometric projection.

Am I working correctly with isometric tilemap system? Or is this sort of unity's bug?

Upd: here is the source code of the script that I wrote
Here how I instantiate tilemap

```
public class BaseTilemapInit : MonoBehaviour

    {
        [SerializeField]
        private Tilemap _tilemap;
        [SerializeField]
        private Tile _tilePrefab;
        [SerializeField]
        private int _width;
        [SerializeField]
        private int _height;
        [SerializeField] private float _tileWidth = 1.0f;
        [SerializeField] private float _tileHeight = 0.5f;
        
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            Instantiate();
            _tilemap.CompressBounds();
        }
    
        public void Instantiate(){
            int offsetX = _width/2;
            int offsetY = _height/2;
    
            for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++){
                    _tilemap.SetTile (new Vector3Int (x, y, 0), _tilePrefab);
                }
            }
        }
    
        public int GetWidth()
        {
            return _width;
        }
    
        public int GetHeight()
        {
            return _height;
        }
    
        public float GetTileWidth()
        {
            return _tileWidth;
        }
    
        public float GetTileHeitht()
        {
            return _tileHeight;
        }
        public Tilemap GetTilemap()
        {
            return _tilemap;
        }
    }
```

And here is a camera controller which is responsible for positioning and rotating (okay not camera but anyway)

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //[SerializeField]
    //private Tilemap _tilemap;
    [SerializeField] private BaseTilemapInit _tiles;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _cam;
    private Tilemap _tilemap;
    private CameraControls cameraActions;
    private InputAction rotation;
    private Transform cameraTransform;

    void Start()
    {
        SetStartCameraPosition();
    }

    private void SetStartCameraPosition()
    {
        float width = _tiles.GetWidth();
        float height = _tiles.GetHeight();

        Vector2 gridCenter = new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2);
        Vector2 isoCenter = GridToIsometric(gridCenter);
        _cam.transform.position = new Vector3(isoCenter.x, isoCenter.y, _cam.transform.position.z);
    }

    private Vector2 GridToIsometric(Vector2 gridPos) {
        
        float tileWidth = _tiles.GetTileWidth(); 
        float tileHeight = _tiles.GetTileHeitht(); 

        float isoX = (gridPos.x - gridPos.y) * tileWidth * 0.5f;
        float isoY = (gridPos.x + gridPos.y) * tileHeight * 0.5f;
        return new Vector2(isoX, isoY);
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        cameraActions = new CameraControls();
        cameraTransform = this.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().transform;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        cameraActions.Camera.RotateClockwise.performed += RotateClockwise;
        cameraActions.Camera.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        cameraActions.Camera.RotateClockwise.performed -= RotateClockwise;
        cameraActions.Camera.Disable();
    }

    private void RotateClockwise(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        _tilemap = _tiles.GetTilemap();
        Debug.Log("Pressed E");
        Rotate (_tilemap);
    }

    void Rotate(Tilemap tilemap)
    {
        BoundsInt bounds = tilemap.cellBounds;

        for (int x = bounds.xMin; x < bounds.xMax; x++){
            for (int y = bounds.yMin; y < bounds.yMax; y++){
                Vector3Int position = new Vector3Int (x, y, 0);
                TileBase tile = tilemap.GetTile(position);
                if (tile != null){
                    Debug.Log ($"Tile {tile.name} at {position}");


                    Vector3Int newposition = Rotatation(position);
                    //Vector3Int newposition = IsoToCart(position);
                    tilemap.SetTile(position, null);
                    tilemap.SetTile(newposition, tile);  
                }
                else{
                    Debug.Log($"No tile at {position}");
                }
            }
        }
        //_tiles.GetTilemap().CompressBounds();
    }

    private Vector3Int Rotatation(Vector3Int pos)
    {
        int x = pos.x;
        int y = pos.y;
        int z = pos.z;

        int newX = (-1) * y;
        int newY = (1) * x;

        Vector3Int newPos = new Vector3Int(newX, newY, pos.z);

        return newPos;
    } 
    private Vector3Int IsoToCart(Vector3Int pos)
    {
        int x = pos.x;
        int y = pos.y;
        int z = pos.z;

        int newX = (x - y)/2;
        int newY = (x + y)/2;

        Vector3Int newPos = new Vector3Int(newX, newY, z);

        return newPos;
    }
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Tilemap tilemap = _tiles.GetTilemap();
        if (tilemap != null)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
            BoundsInt bounds = tilemap.cellBounds;
            Vector3Int min = bounds.min;
            Vector3Int max = bounds.max;

            Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
            corners[0] = tilemap.CellToWorld(new Vector3Int(min.x, min.y, min.z));
            corners[1] = tilemap.CellToWorld(new Vector3Int(max.x, min.y, min.z));
            corners[2] = tilemap.CellToWorld(new Vector3Int(max.x, max.y, min.z));
            corners[3] = tilemap.CellToWorld(new Vector3Int(min.x, max.y, min.z));

            Gizmos.DrawLine(corners[0], corners[1]);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(corners[1], corners[2]);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(corners[2], corners[3]);
            Gizmos.DrawLine(corners[3], corners[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you want to use [GetCellCenterWorld](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetCellCenterWorld.html) to convert the integer tile grid coordinates into the floating point coordinates where the tile is positioned in world space?

Comment: Actually I am trying to rotate grid using (x, y) => (y, -x). But it is work bad in isometric projection

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code you're using.

Comment: I updated my post an provided a source code

Comment: Well it seems I have understand the key problem. It is that I am a newbie here.
I just found that for some reason tilemap somehow 'remember' that tile was on it cell and somehow 2 different tiles get at the same place. But I thought that the reason is in cordinate system.
So I modified my code and first store all new positions in dictionary and then clear all tiles and then set tiles on tilemap from dictionary.
Seems that for now it works as I expected

Comment: Want to edit your question to clarify what the real problem was, then post your solution as an Answer below?

Comment: From what I can tell you would probably struggle rotating isometric tiles because they aren't actually isometric, there are "faked", they are just diamonds that are made to look 3d, so you cant actually move them in 3d space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally understood how it works.
The key point here is that I try simply to rewrite tiles doing so:

```
for(...){
   ... 
   tilemap.SetTile(position, null);
   tilemap.SetTile(newposition, tile); 
   ...
}
```

So sometimes from diamond-shaped tilemap I got tile at completely wrong positions.

The solution that helps me is:
**Store new position somehow** (I had chosen a Dictionary)

```
Dictionary<Vector3Int, TileBase> tilesPositions = new Dictionary<Vector3Int, TileBase>();
   for(...){
   ...
   Vector3Int newposition = Rotatation(position);//here Rotation do (x, y) -> (-y, x)
   tilesPositions[newposition] = tile; 
  ...
  }
```

Then clear all tiles and set it from Dictionary

```
tilemap.ClearAllTiles();
foreach (var item in tilesPositions)
{
    tilemap.SetTile(item.Key, item.Value);
}
tilemap.CompressBounds();
```